# More than one query for more than one resultSet

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I want to retrieve data from one database using 3 WHERE conditions, and the data should be listed on the same table on my web application, on the same row, different column.

this is what I have for one WHERE condition, but I cannot find a way around to fit all the results within the same table that I am building on my web app.

```
try
{
        //Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        //Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:db1","","");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/etoolsco_VecinetSM?user=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD");
        Statement statement=connection.createStatement();
        String query;
        query="SELECT * FROM flatene2013 WHERE Apto='5C'";
        ResultSet resultSet=statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(resultSet.next())
    {%>
    <tr>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><font size="-1"><%out.println(resultSet.getBigDecimal(4)+"");%></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><font size="-1"><%out.println(resultSet.getBigDecimal(5)+"");%></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it a matter of sql or out layer issue? For SQL you can do multiple conditions in one query or use `case when`... Not very clear of what you need sorry :$

Comment: @bonCodigo if I use multiple conditions in one query, how would I get them listed with resultSet? first condition completed, then second, then third, etc? that is my doubt.

Comment: You have mentioned *using 3 WHERE conditions, and the data should be listed on the same table on my web application, on the same row, different column.*... That sounds like a usual basic `Select col1, col2, col3 from table where col1 = condition1 and col2 = 'condition2' and col3 = condition3`...Unless you want to select different data and `UNION` then into one table.. So please show us your 3 where conditions and your table data and results you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Best guess here is that you may be looking for a `UNION` of three rows returned by 3 different/independent conditions. Is this what you need for e.g.?

```
SELECT * FROM flatene2013 WHERE Apto='5C'
UNION
SELECT * FROM flatene2013 WHERE Apto='6C'
UNION
SELECT * FROM flatene2013 WHERE Apto='7C';
```

Please note it's rather not effective to suggest answers without knowing your tables schema...or logic you are after..

Comment: Thanks, yes that is what I am after, I will try and let you know the outcome.  You are right about my question, it was not composed correctly.  Apologies for that.

Comment: I tried the example but I have issues in the code saying that I need to close each line with ";" ... but I was thinking that if I tried to place this value in a normal <table> html, the 3 values would be in the same cell, so I need to place them separate.

Comment: You may wrap them all with brackets and try this: `select x.* from (select... union select.... union select...)x`